# mysqlt error 1054 unknown column?

Tags: php, sql, xml

I've been mashing away at tweaking a calendar event to prepare it so I can just have a user click add to calendar and it will fire off code for that (that much works) but I'm trying to add an end date to the event in the db and it's not having any of it when I try to insert it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema version="0.3">
<table name="dsEventCalendar">
    <field name="calendarID" type="I">
        <key/>
        <unsigned/>
        <autoincrement/>
    </field>
    <field name="title" type="C" size="255">
    </field>
</table>
<table name="dsEventCalendarEvents">
    <field name="eventID" type="I">
        <key/>
        <unsigned/>
        <autoincrement/>
    </field>
    <field name="calendarID" type="I">
        <unsigned/>
    </field>
    <field name="date" type="T">
    </field>
    <field name="type" type="C" size="255">
    </field>
    <field name="title" type="C" size="255">
    </field>
    <field name="description" type="X">
    </field>
    <field name="url" type="X">
    </field>
    <field name="endDate" type="X">
    </field>
    </table>
</schema>
```

and here's my php code that seems to fail

```
$this->post('event_title');
             $this->post('event_date');
             $this->post('event_location');
             $this->post('event_description');
             $this->post('event_url');
             $this->post('event_endDate');
             $sql = "INSERT INTO dsEventCalendarEvents(calendarID,title,date,type,description,url,endDate) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
             $args = array(
                   $this->post('event_calendarID'),
                   $this->post('event_title'),
                   $this->post('event_date'),
                   $this->post('event_location'),
                   $this->post('event_description'),
                   $this->post('event_url'),
                   $this->post('event_endDate')
             );
             $db->Execute($sql, $args); //death, immediate death
             echo "killed";
```

If anyone could see the dumb mistake I'm probably creating that would be fantastic as I'm at a loss.

Comment: So what's the table definition on your database?

Comment: could you possibly point me in the direction to find it? I'm getting my stuff from this git repo https://github.com/dszymczuk/dsEventCalendar/ and xml db's are new to me.

Comment: Is this an XML database? It looks like you're just doing a normal SQL query to me, and the error suggests that it's a MySQL database

Comment: that's weird, when my hopeful column is not there, it functions perfectly, adds the event and all the information. my hopeful column throws a wrench in the system and I'm not sure why.

Comment: it was an issue with the block not wanting to refresh...this was in Concrete5, that could have been important...so we forced it into the table. All is good now.

Comment: @snurby77, would you mind posting what you just wrote as an answer and then accepting it? That way, other people visiting this question and experiencing the same problem will be able to jump right to it.